# Angular 4.4 - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, angular

I've reduced this to its simplest form as below:

```
<select (change)="switch()" [hidden]="visible" [(ngModel)]="model">
  <option *ngFor="let amount of [1,2,3]" [ngValue]="amount"> {{amount}} </option>
</select>

<div [hidden]="!visible">... we swap places</div>
```

---

```
export class SomeComponent {

  model = 1;
  visible = false;

  switch() {
    if (this.visible === 3) {
    this.visible = true;
  }

}
```

This seems to work fine, however it also throws: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.`

How do I change it before it gets checked here?

Comment: read the article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this by explicitly triggering the change,

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

switch() {
    if (this.visible === 3) {
      this.visible = true;
      this.cdr.detectionChanges();
      ...
}
```

Comment: It is ChangeDetectorRef and this.cdr.detectChanges() on mine. This is what I was looking for though, thanks!

Comment: cant yet, your reply was too fast